# How to convert PDF file content from blob to PDF Readable format in React JS

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

Problem Statement : I am trying to download PDF from the content fetched from the blob storage.

Tried : I am trying to read PDF content from Blob and converting it into buffer format and then trying to download but it doesn't work. The pdf file is getting downloaded but when i try opening the pdf - it says error loading PDF document.

Solution i had tried :-

Server Side Code

```
 const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobSASToken);
 const containerName = blob_container;
 const subContName = appConfig.blob.folder;
 const subContName = blob_folder;
 const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
 const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(offerLetterName);
 const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download();
 const downloaded: any = await streamToBuffer(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody);
 return downloaded;
```

```
 const streamToBuffer = async (readableStream: any) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks: any = [];
    readableStream.on('data', (data: any) => {
      chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
    });
    readableStream.on('end', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
    readableStream.on('error', reject);
  });
};
```

Client Side Code

```
const download = (data: any) => {
  const blob = new Blob([data.data as Buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = 'test.pdf';
  link.click();
};
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

***I tried below react js code to convert a PDF  blob file content to PDF Readable format.***

Firstly, I uploaded a sample PDF file as blob to my storage account container as below:

[image]

My project structure looks like below,

[image]

**Code:**

**PDFDownloader.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';

class PDFDownloader extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.downloadPDF = this.downloadPDF.bind(this);
  }

  downloadPDF() {
    fetch('/download-pdf')
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = '<PDF-blob-name>';
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>PDF Downloader</h1>
        <button onClick={this.downloadPDF}>Download PDF</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PDFDownloader;
```

**index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PDFDownloader from './components/PDFDownloader';
ReactDOM.render(<PDFDownloader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PDF Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>PDF Downloader</h1>
  <a href="/download-pdf" download="<PDF-blob-name>">Download PDF</a>

  <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = require('./router');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**router.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const router = express.Router();

const downloadPDFFromBlob = async (containerName, blobName) => {
  const connectionString = "<storage-conne-string>";

  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  const downloadResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
  const buffer = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
  return buffer;
};

const streamToBuffer = async (readableStream) => {
  const chunks = [];
  for await (const chunk of readableStream) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  }
  return Buffer.concat(chunks);
};

router.get('/download-pdf', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const containerName = '<containe-name>';
    const blobName = '<PDF-blob-name>';

    const buffer = await downloadPDFFromBlob(containerName, blobName);

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="<PDF-blob-name>"');
    res.send(buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error downloading PDF');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "pdf-downloader-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "PDF Downloader project",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above output URL, I can able to downlad the PDF blob like below,

[image]

***I can able to read the PDF blob data as below,***

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution , The file is getting downloaded but it is showing as Failed to Load PDF document.

Comment: Is there any screen sharing session or any link i can connect you , If you are ok with that.